# TextView is unclickable in application

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am designing a pop up AlertDialog that sets the view of of the alert dialog to the following XML file. For some reason the file will not add margins and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Margins and Padding do not work in the activity_priority_level_values LinearLayout, the LinearLayout that holds all of the TextViews, or any of the TextViews. How can I add margins (or padding) for the dialogs borders and margins between all of the text views?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_priority_level_values"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/large_space">
<TextView  android:id="@+id/level_1_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/level_1_header"/>

<TextView  android:id="@+id/level_1_decription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/level_1_description"/>

<TextView  android:id="@+id/level_2_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/level_2_header"/>

<TextView  android:id="@+id/level_2_decription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/mid_space"
    android:text="@string/level_2_description"/>

<TextView  android:id="@+id/level_3_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/level_3_header"/>

<TextView  android:id="@+id/level_3_decription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/mid_space"
    android:text="@string/level_3_description"/>

<TextView  android:id="@+id/level_4_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/level_4_header"/>

<TextView  android:id="@+id/level_4_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/mid_space"
    android:text="@string/level_4_description"/>

<TextView  android:id="@+id/level_5_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/level_5_header"/>

<TextView  android:id="@+id/level_5_decription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/level_5_description"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
LinearLayout hiddenLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_priority_level_values);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

if(hiddenLayout == null){
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_law_priority);
    View hiddenInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_priority_level_values, null);
    builder.setView(hiddenInfo);
}
builder.create();
builder.show();
```

Comment: AlertDialog always does that.. but I am confused with the question.. is it the textView being unclickable or the ALertDialog problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the inflating of your view.

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_law_priority);
View hiddenInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_priority_level_values, null);
```

You should never inflate with null. Instead change the code to:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_law_priority);
View hiddenInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_priority_level_values, myLayout, false);
```

If you are inflating with null the layout params will be ignored.